# Removing duplicates in a nested, cross-referenced list

Tags: c#, reference, nested, duplicates, cross-reference

I am aware that title might be misleading and common answer can be 'go search again', however I have searched stack overflow as much as I could and I didn't find an answer that would satisfy me.

**Introduction**

I need to create an algorithm that will remove all the similar items in a nested, cross-referenced list.

General rules:

- Items can have children and can reference other items.
- Object cannot reference another object and have children at the same time.
- There can be a lot of objects in a list (up to 100k), there are ALWAYS up to 1 level of depth for children, but unknown, variable-length reference chains for each object.
- Reference chains are not infinite, they usually have up to 5-15 elements and always ends up with an object of known ClassType field.
- There can be 'dead chains' - an items that are not referenced by any of the objects but they reference other objects.
- Children of objects are NOT a part of a list - they can reference another elements, but cannot be referenced on it's own.
- In order to compare two objects their properties has to be same as well as their children (if they exists) and a referenced object (if it exists).
- When comparing children or referenced object, same rules apply.
- Unique ID is assigned to every object (this is NOT a hash code, rather than order of object creation) - two object will be same despite different id they have. There will be no objects with same ID.

Memory requirements as well as CPU occupancy are not specified - high performance is preferred. My current approach (brute-force method that compares every object with another one) is to slow and can take up to 1 hour of runtime. Prefered execution speed would be up to 1 minute. Also my way iterate collection infinite times as long, as same objects were found and it's using only single thread. I would love to get multi-threaded more deterministic approach.

**Description**

Consider following object definition:

```
public enum ClassType
{
  Type_Base,
  Type_A,
  Type_B,
  Type_C,
};

public class MyObject
{
  public string Name { get; }
  public uint ID { get; }
  public ClassType ClassType { get; }

  public uint ReferencedID { get; }
  public List<MyObject> Children { get; } = new List<MyObject>( );
}
```

And a collections indexed with a ID property of MyObject, for fast access:

```
Dictionary<uint, MyObject> Preserved; // Top-most objects, has to be preserved
Dictionary<uint, MyObject> AllObjects; // Dictionary of all objects
```

Additionaly, consider following comparison method:

```
public static bool AreObjectsSame( MyObject l, MyObject r, Dictionary<uint, MyObject> allObjects )
{
  // Null-Check
  if ( l is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( l ) );
  if ( r is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( r ) );
  if ( allObjects is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( allObjects ) );

  // Compare class type and name
  if ( l.ClassType != r.ClassType ) return false;
  if ( l.Name != null && r.Name != null && !l.Name.Equals( r.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCulture ) ) return false;
  
  // Compare referenced ID objects
  if ( l.ReferencedID != 0 && r.ReferencedID != 0 )
  {
    if ( !AreObjectsSame( allObjects[ l.ReferencedID ], allObjects[ r.ReferencedID ], allObjects ) ) return false;
  }

  // Compare children objects
  if ( l.Children.Count != r.Children.Count ) return false;
  for ( int i = 0; i < l.Children.Count; ++i )
  {
    if ( !AreObjectsSame( l.Children[ i ], r.Children[ i ], allObjects ) ) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Now let's examine a chain of objects. Objects having children works in a similar manner, therefore I will skip them for sake of explanation simplicity.

```
MyObject ("Name_A", Type_A) -> MyObject ("Name_B", Type_B) -> MyObject ("Name_C", Type_A) -> MyObject ("Name_D", Type_Base)
MyObject ("Name_E", Type_C) -> MyObject ("Name_F", Type_C) -> MyObject ("Name_C", Type_A) -> MyObject ("Name_D", Type_Base)
MyObject ("Name_G", Type_A) -> MyObject ("Name_D", Type_Base)
```

As you can see, we have 10 objects placed in *AllObjects* dictionary. In each reference chain we have objects *("Name_C", Type_A)* and *("Name_D", Type_Base)*. Since objects *("Name_D", Type_Base)* are equal (they have the same type and name), objects *("Name_C", Type_A)* are also equal (they have the same type and name plus their referenced objects are same).

Now, I we can optimize above chain of objects into something like this:

```
MyObject ("Name_A", Type_A) -> MyObject ("Name_B", Type_B) -> MyObject ("Name_C", Type_A) -> MyObject ("Name_D", Type_Base)
MyObject ("Name_E", Type_C) -> MyObject ("Name_F", Type_C) ->-|
MyObject ("Name_G", Type_A) -------------------------------->-/
```

This lead us to removing 3 duplicated nodes and rearanging reference id for two of them.

**Possible Solution**

One of the possible solution would be to precalculate for each element its own hash code and use this hash to compare elements in a brute force manner. If comparison is true, then perform field-by-field comparison (to eliminate possible collisions in hash codes).

Is there any better way of removing duplicates? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Some fast suggestions:

1. yes, precalculate hashcode and do in-depth comparison only on items having same hashcode
2. dont examine B against A after A was once examined against B, take items in some order and do examine item at index X only against indices greater than X
3. do not remove items during comparison but collect the items to-be-left in separate collection and drop the original one at the end
4. use well indexable collections like array during an algorithm which goes through all items.

**But first of all** use some profiler tools like Redgate's Performance Profiler. A lot of times I was "optimizing" the algorithm using my intuition without any measurable success but making it much less understandable. After trying a profiler it turned out that a who-the-hell-would-think-of-that code, e.g. string operations, overused object instantiations take much more time than my algorithm! The profiler can point you to the code which **really** needs optimalization :)